# How to accurately gauge memory usage in Elastic Beanstalk/EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, memory-usage, elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk environment running a nodejs server. I'm trying to gauge memory usage to determine which instance type is most appropriate, and how much memory we actually need. To do so, I connected to the server via ssh at the time when the server's usage peaked and ran the `free` and `top` commands, getting the following results:

top:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND  
27607 nodejs    20   0  944m 146m  27m S  15.2  3.9  25:04.26 node               
 2384 root      24   4  626m 118m 8932 S   0.7  3.2  67:34.94 aws                
 3235 root      20   0  524m  29m 8628 S   0.3  0.8   6:19.01 cfn-hup            
17626 nginx     20   0 68964  14m 3728 S   0.3  0.4   8:07.17 nginx              
31893 ec2-user  20   0 15364 2116 1828 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.02 top                
    1 root      20   0 19692 2672 2252 S   0.0  0.1   0:02.18 init
```

(everything else had %mem of 0.0)

free:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3824772    3654360     170412         60     108792    2956936
-/+ buffers/cache:     588632    3236140
Swap:            0          0          0
```

So, `free` seems to indicate memory usage is at 95.5%, but less than 4% is being used by the nodejs process, and all of the processes in `top` sum to only 8.5%. What exactly is going on here? Where is the other 87% going? Should I be using a smaller instance based on the fact that the nodejs process only uses 4% of memory and 15% of CPU? Or do I need a bigger instance based on the fact that memory usage is already at 95.5%? If traffic were to increase enough that the memory usage of the nodejs process tripled, would the server run out of memory and crash, or would it re-allocate some of that mysterious 87% to the nodejs process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory management in Linux may be little confusing to some people who aren't familiar with it. Basically, a few things that can come to play here, is either virtual memory balooning, or kernel has used the memory for various tasks and processes, but has not freed it up yet. If your node.js process required more memory, then the kernel can free it up to use for your application.

You can see in your output in the 2nd line of 'free' that -/+ buffers/cache you have free 3236140 KB of memory (3.2GB). Most of this memory can be available to your application if needed.

-/+ buffers/cache:     588632    **3236140**

Comment: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ is a good site with a simple explanation of this